# What's a good way to prepare vegan corn on the cob without too much of a price difference?

Tags: substitutions, vegan

The cheapest is to just forgo using better, but are there a simple substitutes to butter/margarine? Or is there an alternative way to prepare ears of corn without animal products, yet still retains some basic taste?

I am looking for an alternative to drenching sweet corn in butter that's not too fancy. I suppose this question can be expanded for all entrees heavily dependent on butter. (It's usually easy to come up with butter alternatives for cooking, and that's not what I'm asking.)

Comment: Why not margarine?

Comment: Margarine isn't vegan.

Comment: Vegan margarine is quite easy to find.

Comment: I assumed the price was significantly higher.

Comment: Unless you're spreading like a pound of margarine on your ear of corn, the total price increase will not be significant, no.

Comment: I suppose per once of this one ingredient, $0.07 for margarine vs $0.20 for vegetable oil spread, isn't significant.

Comment: Where do you live? In Sweden, dairy-free margarine is available everywhere and costs like margarine with dairy.

Comment: what about a good olive or avocado oil - expensive though.

Comment: I live in the US.

Comment: @bob1 : but you're using so little that the difference in cost tends to not be significant.  You just need a quick rub down (oiled paper towel or a sprayer) to get salt to stick.

Comment: In the UK vegan spreads (margarine) are cheaper than butter, as is a lot of olive oil. I don't recall butter being very cheap in the US, but didn't check the spread we bought

Comment: "Classical margarine is mainly made from a combination of vegetable oil, salt, and water. However, it usually still does contain animal products..."

Comment: @adamaero look for kosher ones. They are all totally vegan.

Comment: Try it street corn style. Slathered with (vegan) mayo & a sprinkling of chili powder and or lime juice if you like. (Leaving off the cheese of course).

Answer (score 7):

"Dairy-free margarine" is available at any supermarket.
It's half the price of a supermarket 'econo-saver' butter, pound for pound & a quarter the price of a premium, Lurpak, President etc.

If you want something a bit less 'artificial' try a spray of olive oil & a light sprinkle of salt. Half the point of putting butter on corn is the added salt anyway.

'Fun' alternatives - chilli oil, garlic oil, basil oil, pesto...

Comment: And make it a good quality olive oil. Don't cheap out, if you're using it as a condiment you need one that tastes good (and you won't need much for something like this).